# Net::SFTP Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sftp, net-sftp

I have been trying to download a file using Net::SFTP and it keeps getting an error.

The file is partially downloaded, and is only 2.1 MB, so it's not a huge file. I removed the loop over the files and even tried just downloading the one file and got the same error:

```
yml = YAML.load_file Rails.root.join('config', 'ftp.yml')
Net::SFTP.start(yml["url"], yml["username"], password: yml["password"]) do |sftp|
  sftp.dir.glob(File.join('users', 'import'), '*.csv').each do |f|
    sftp.download!(File.join('users', 'import', f.name), Rails.root.join('processing_files', 'download_files', f.name), read_size: 1024)
  end
end
```

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `close' for #<Pathname:0x007fc8fdb50ea0>
from /[my_working_ap_dir]/gems/net-sftp-2.1.2/lib/net/sftp/operations/download.rb:331:in `on_read'
```

I have prayed to Google all I can and am not getting anywhere with it.

Comment: show us the code which caused the error

Comment: From the error "undefined method close" I'd guess it just failed because you scoped a resource that doesn't support the "close" operation. Are you sure the file doesn't get completely read? It might not get fully written simply because no one thinks to put `flush`es after every write, but do you call `close` or scope a resource in such a way that the language might implicitly call `close` on it after it falls out of the enclosing block? Because if that's you're issue all you need to do is remove that `close` and you'll be riding the bandwagon to the gravy train in no time.

Comment: `Rails.root` returns a Pathname object, but it looks like the sftp code doesn't check to see whether it got a Pathname or a File handle, it just runs with it. When it runs into `entry.sink.close` it crashes because Pathnames don't implement `close`. Pathnames are great for manipulating paths to files and directories, but they're not substitutes for file handles. You could probably tack on `to_s` which would return a string. See `ri Net::SFTP::Operations::Download` for more info.

Comment: @theTinMan if you want to provide this as an answer I will mark it as the answer. That is a great explanation of what was going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Rails.root` returns a [Pathname](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html) object, but it looks like the sftp code doesn't check to see whether it got a Pathname or a File handle, it just runs with it. When it runs into `entry.sink.close` it crashes because Pathnames don't implement close.

Pathnames are great for manipulating paths to files and directories, but they're not substitutes for file handles. You could probably tack on `to_s` which would return a string.

Here's a summary of the `download` call from the documentation that *hints* that the expected parameters should be a String:

```
To download a single file from the remote server, simply specify both the
remote and local paths:

  downloader = sftp.download("/path/to/remote.txt", "/path/to/local.txt")
```

I suspect that if I dig into the code it will check to see whether the parameters are strings, and, if not, assumes that they are IO handles.

See `ri Net::SFTP::Operations::Download` for more info.

---

Here's an excerpt from the current `download!` code, and you can see how the problem occurred:

```
def download!(remote, local=nil, options={}, &block)
  require 'stringio' unless defined?(StringIO)
  destination = local || StringIO.new
  result = download(remote, destination, options, &block).wait
  local ? result : destination.string
end
```

`local` was passed in as a Pathname. The code checks to see if there's something passed in, but not what that is. If nothing is passed in it assumes it's something with IO-like features, which is what StringIO provides for the in-memory caching.

Comment: but the user is actually giving arguments for `local` too .. so here it is not getting converted to `StringIO` and the summary of the download call clearly accepts a string as an argument.. So this needs more reasoning for this behaviour ..

Comment: Your comment is quite late. Based on the code in place at the time the OP felt it explained the problem.

Comment: Yeah true my comment is quite late, but still I wanted to fill the missing gaps so that it helps other developers who face this issue..

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you can't use `Rails.root.join`, which was causing the problem. It is really stupid though because it would download part of the file.

Changed:

```
sftp.download!(File.join('users', 'import', f.name), Rails.root.join('processing_files', 'download_files', f.name))
```

To:

```
sftp.download!(File.join('users', 'import', f.name), File.join('processing_files', 'download_files', f.name))
```

Comment: How is this different from the previous approach? Because `File.join(*)` still returns a `String` object and neither does it respond to `#close` method

Comment: I addressed the above commented myself in the answers section..

Answer (score 0):

*argument `remote` can be a `Pathname` object while argument `local` when set should be a `String` or else an object that responds to `#write` method*.
Below is the working code

```
local_stringified_path = Rails.root.join('processing_files', f.name).to_s
sftp.download!(Pathname.new('/users/import'), local_stringified_path)
```

For all those curious minds please read below to understand this behaviour..

The issue  `NoMethodError: undefined method close' for #<Pathname:0x007fc8fdb50ea0>` happens exactly [here](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-sftp/blob/master/lib/net/sftp/operations/download.rb#L332)
in the `#on_read` method and below is the code snippet of the concerned statements.

```
if response.eof? 
   update_progress(:close, entry)
   entry.sink.close # ERRORED OUT LINE.. ideally when eof, file IO handler is supposed to be closed
```

**WHAT IS `entry.sink` ?**

We know already that `#download!` methods takes two args as below

```
sftp.download!(remote, local)
```

The given args `remote` and `local` is converted to an Entry object [here](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-sftp/blob/master/lib/net/sftp/operations/download.rb#L162)

```
[Entry.new(remote, local, recursive?)]
```

and `Entry` is a nothing but a `Struct` [here](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-sftp/blob/master/lib/net/sftp/operations/download.rb#L207)

```
Entry = Struct.new(:remote, :local, :directory, :size, :handle, :offset, :sink)
```

okay then what is `sink` attribute? we will jump to that right away..

Once the concerned remote file is open to be read, the `#on_open` method updates this `sink` attribute with a File handler [here](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-sftp/blob/master/lib/net/sftp/operations/download.rb#L311).

Find the snippet below,

```
entry.sink = entry.local.respond_to?(:write) ? entry.local : ::File.open(entry.local, "wb")
```

**This actually happens only when given `local` path object doesn't implement it's own `#write` method** In our scenario, `Pathname` objects does respond to [write](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-write)

Below are some snippets of the console outputs, I inspected in between multiple download chunk calls while debugging this.. which shows the `entry` and `entry.sink` displaying the above discussed objects.
Here I chose my remote to be a `Pathname` object and local to be `String` path which returns proper value for the `entry.sink` and there by downloading successfully..

```
0> entry 
=> #<struct Net::SFTP::Operations::Download::Entry remote=#<Pathname:214010463.xml>, local="214010463.xml", directory=nil, size=nil, handle="1", offset=32000, sink=#<File:214010463.xml>>


0> entry.sink
=> #<File:214010463.xml>
```